# Extended Array Class in Javascript: How should I create helper functions to modify Array without assigning a new reference?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, reference, closures

This is a socket.io lobby library for managing the users list.
I created an Array extension class with custom methods. My removeUser method does not work.
Logging shows that inside of the method, it does work - the user has been removed.
Logging outside shows no change.

I believe my issue is one of references. The reference in index.js 'userList' is one reference.
`var userList = require("./userList")();`
However when I reassign userList in the method, it creates another reference.
`userArray = result;`
This newly-created reference is not known by the index.js, which sees no change in the userList object.

**index.js**
My server (simplified for example)

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();

const server = require("http").createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(server);

var userList = require("./userList")();

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  // get user from session
  userList.addUser(s_user);
  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    userList.removeUser(s_user);
  });
});
```

**userList.js** (Original)
An extended Array class for managing the list of users in my lobby.

```
function createUserList() {
  
  let userArray = [];

  userArray.addUser = (user) => {
    userArray.push(user);
  };

  userArray.removeUser = (user) => {
    let userId = user.user_id;
    for (let i = 0; i < userArray.length; i++) {
      if (userArray[i]["user_id"] === userId && userId !== undefined) {
        let firstHalf = userArray.slice(0, i);
        let secondHalf = userArray.slice(i+1, userArray.length);
        let result = firstHalf.concat(secondHalf);
        userArray = result;
      }
    }
  };

  return userArray;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to modify array instances? At the very least, I'd expect a `class MyArray extends Array` so you properly extend it and have more control over the resulting arrays. However, if you're only doing removal, that should be fairly trivial with existing array methods such as `.filter()` or `.findIndex()` + `.splice()` (if you want to do it in-place). What is the reason to create an entirely new remove functionality?

Comment: I guess a small part of it is my inexperience. Another part is preference to create human readable-code, and for grouping similar code into libraries with simple APIs. I suspect I will add another handful of of methods to this library over time.

Comment: `removeUser = (userId, arr) => arr.filter(user => userId !== undefined && user.user_id !== userId)`. Here is a library function using idiomatic code to work within your application's domain. It's one line, with no need to add more hacky workaround like attaching method to array instances which would get lost, thus necessitating to create a wrapper around the array class that just reinvents the array class.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. That code does seem pretty straightforward. So.. basically you are saying, the built-in methods do a sufficient job and are concise. Making it efficient and still human readable.

Answer (score 0):

**My Solution**
My solution was to create a closure. An array manager object contains the methods for userList management, and through a closure has access to the userArray. (code below this paragraph)
Pros

- The userArray can modified or reassigned without reference issue (within the userList library)
  `userArray = [] //ok`
  (I also don't have to re-attach methods on re-assignment)

Cons

- I can't use Array prototype methods
  `let length = userList.length // method doesn't exist on management object`
  `let listCopy = userList // returns an object, not the list`
  I must use my custom built methods
  `let length = userList.getLength()`
  `let listCopy = userList.getList()`

**Does anyone have other interesting solutions?**

**userList.js** (V2)

```
function createUserList() {

  let userArray = []

  let arrayManager = {

    addUser: (user) => {
      userArray.push(user);
    },

    removeUser: (user) => {
      let userId = user.user_id;
      for (let i = 0; i < userArray.length; i++) {
        if (userArray[i]["user_id"] === userId && userId !== undefined) {
          let firstHalf = userArray.slice(0, i);
          let secondHalf = userArray.slice(i+1, userArray.length);
          let result = firstHalf.concat(secondHalf);
          userArray = result;
        }
      }
    },

    getList: () => {
      return userArray;
    },

    getLength: () => {
      return userArray.length;
    }
  };

  return arrayManager;
}

module.exports = createUserList;
```